# copying a large video file from iPhone to external hard drive hangs

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, iphone

I connected my iPhone 4S as well as my Toshiba external hard drive to my Dell Windows 7 laptop.  For relatively small files I can use Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V to copy directly from the iPhone to the external hard drive.  But for large video files (around 500MB) the copy hangs.

I discovered a workaround, which is to copy the file from the iPhone to the laptop's internal hard drive, then from the hard drive to the external drive, which works.  How can I get the copy to work directly for these large files?

Comment: How many USB ports does the laptop have? Try different combinations to connect the iPhone and external drive to the laptop. If that doesn't help, try connecting both to a powered USB hub.

Comment: Should I suspect a defect in either of them?

Comment: Not a defect, I was thinking more along the lines of possible bandwidth constraints while connecting both devices to ports from the same root hub.